# Как загрузить проект С++ в Qt Creator?

Tags: qtcreator, qt, c++, build

Как загрузить проект с github в Qt Creator и скомпилировать его там? Я пытаюсь собрать вот этот проект: https://github.com/msakhnik/alarm#alarm. Проект простой - написан на чистом C++.

Comment: Нажать на меню "Файл" и последовательно выбирать из меню нужные пункты, однако. Там же все чёрным по белому написано, и вариантов куча. Хочешь - новый проект создавай и вручную файлы добавляй, хочешь - импортируешь прямо из гита, только мышкой тыкай. Секунд пять :)



![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/Oku8LkH.png

Comment: Я все так и сделал: Файл - Новый файл или проект - Импортировать проект - Импорт существующего проекта. Но в этои режиме Qt Creator работает как редактор и при попытке компиляции говорит: No rule to make target `all'.  Stop. Там как-то среду сборке нужно настроить и как я не знаю.

Comment: Ну вот что сразу-то проблему не описать нормально? Значит, что-то не так с qmake. Попробуйте создать через "Простой проект на C++ (сборка CMake)", там будет кнопочка "запустить cmake" для генерации makefile. (это я про линкус, конечно, как оно под windows - не знаю)

Вот, создал через cmake, сразу всё собирается:

![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/asiVd91.png

Comment: Как ты это сделал? Покажи шаги. У меня Mac OS и Qt 5.2

Comment: Вынесу в ответ, тут места мало.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предполагаем, что каталог `/home/klopp/dev/alarm-master` есть, и в нём лежат исходники. Qt под Linux Mint.

[image]

Файл -> Новый файл или проект, там:

[image]

Дальше стандартные вопросы: пути, какие конфигурации собирать и т.д:

[image]

Идём до конца, последним будет вопрос "файл main.cpp уже существует, перезаписать?". Отвечаем "нет уж, свой есть!" :) Сразу после этого появляется такое окно, жмём "запуск cmake":

[image]

Оно пошуршит, сгенерит файлы для сборки. Всё, готово